# How to reduce boilerplate typing with type maps?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typing

I'm sending and handling websocket messages with multiplexing WebSocketSubject in RxJs.

Method `.message` takes MessageType as first parameter and some optional data as second.
I'm trying to automatically map response type based on this parameter.
Currently I have this:

```
enum MessageType {
    LogIn = 'login'
    // ...
}

public login(credentials: Credentials): Observable<SocketResponse<LogInResponse>> {
    return this.ws
        .multiplex(
            () => this.ws.message(MessageType.LogIn, credentials),
            () => {}
            (res) => this.ws.filter(res, ResponseType.LogInResponse),
        )
}
```

I waint to transform it with some sort of type mapping(?) into something like this:

```
public login(
  credentials: Credentials
) /** here method auto infers return type as <Observable<SocketResponse<LogInResponse>>> */ {
    return this.ws.multiplexWrapper<MessageType.LogIn or SomeType>(
        // or passing it again as parameter...
        credentials,
        // possibility to override unsubMsg
        // possibility to override default filter but not the mapped ResponseType
    )
}
```

I feel this should be possible.
Any links to documentation, typescript <strike>pseudo</strike>code or how similar techniques is called
will be very appreciated.

Comment: What's the boilerplate in this example? Just the return type of your function? If so, then if your `multiplexWrapper` returns `Observable<SocketResponse<LogInResponse>>` then TS will infer that for you. `MessageType.login` isn't a TS type, it's an enum. TS types exist only at compile-time, but you can pass enum values around at runtime. It's not clear what you mean passing again as parameter.

Comment: @MrkSef I guess I wanted to have map of corresponding types, so typescript could infer them for me like: cast input type NewUser for multiplexWrapper and get NewUserResponse as returned value in inference.